# The file 'xxxxx.asmx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I have a asp.net 4.0 website which has been published using fixed naming and single page assemblies.

All of a sudden we are getting the file 'xxxxx.asmx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested on the webservice page, and only the webservice page.
Everything else works fine, I can see the file in the bin directory and it has the same name as a found in a previous (older) working bin folder.

Also works fine on Windows 7 dev server but not production (IIS 7 Server 2008). I have rebuilt and redeployed the application with no success, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it, turns out just removed the Microsoft.mshtml reference.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean?